# Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.4

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I tried all the solution provided by stackflow for the this issue however I am facing same issue. I tried changing the facet to 3.0 but still the problem is same
Can any one help me out in this please.

pom.xml 
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
      4.0.0
      AMPortal
      AMPortal
      war
      0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
      AMPortal Maven Webapp
      http://maven.apache.org

```
    <properties>
        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <!-- Spring framework END -->
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - START -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security Artifacts - END -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Servlet API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP API -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL JDBC driver -->
        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
    <finalName>AMPortal</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

my web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>


<!-- Loads Spring Security config file -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>        
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
        /WEB-INF/data-source-cfg.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<!-- Spring Security Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Change your web.xml, that is still version 2.4.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 5):

You have the following header in your `web.xml`

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" 
    version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

This basically tells your container (and also eclipse) that this is a 2.4 servlet spec application. Change it to use a 3.0 header instead

```
<web-app
    version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```